# Закинуть django сайт на виртуальный хостинг и привязать домен

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu

где покупать домен и как его привязать если нет админ панели? Сам сервер на Ubuntu. Может кто-нибудь вкратце описать что и как мне делать?

Comment: 1. Обратиться к "регистратору доменов" (спросить эту фразу у гугла), зарегистрировать домен, взять услугу поддержки dns-серверов, обычно у них же. Указать в домене 'A' запись с ip вашего сервера. 2. В конфигурационном файле web-сервера (nginx, apache или что там у вас) описать ваш домен, где лежат файлы и что запускать (конфигурация зависит от используемого wsgi и web-сервера)

Comment: @Mike на onlydomains могу взять?

Comment: Думаю можете. Но вот зачем платить им 35 евро (3000р) за домен .ru на год, если на каком нибудь nic.ru он стоит 590 +900р "DNS хостинг" (т.е. DNS сервер). А например на reg.ru это же все обойдется за 199+199 (видимо какая то акция).

Comment: @Mike домен который я выбрал везде стоит +- одинаково. Самое главное чтоб я мог там же привязать его к хостингу.

Comment: Услуга поддержки DNS серверов у наших регистраторов оказывается отдельно. Как на onlydomains я не знаю

Comment: @Mike Понял. Ну а для стандартной привязки требуется админ панель?

Comment: У регистратора домена всегда есть своя админ панель в которой вы можете либо указать NS записи, если DNS сервера не у них (и это минимум, регистратор доменов по другому не работает). Либо если DNS у них же, то там можно редактировать A записи которые отвечают за преобразование имен домена в ip сервера (хостера). На этом все. Все остальное делается уже на вашем сервере (в данном случае у хостера) и конечно никаких админ панелей что бы что то сделать в полностью доступной операционке не требуется